# Windows Phone 8: Export app data

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, export, file-transfer, transfer

I have a Windows Phone 8 app where users register some simple data in an SQLite database.

As any good data collection app I want the users to be able to export his data to do whatever with. Most notably export to the Android version (where this functionality already exists).

How do I achieve this?

Solutions I have found/considered so far:
*Write to a commonly available area, such as Documents*. Is not implemented on WP.
*Attach it to an email*. Does not exist on WP.
*Save in the public photos folder*. You got to be joking me if this is the only way..
*Transfer through a webservice*. Would be nice but a serious step up from saving a file.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1. This way you'll be able to save to the Documents folder (by using a `FileSavePicker`)

Comment: I think currently the best option you have to put the file on a cloud service like drop box, box, google drive, one drive etc.

Comment: Trying the 8.1 approach